# Why doesn't C++ show a narrowing conversion error when casting a float to a char?

Tags: c++, gcc, narrowing

Compiling this code using `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp` doesn't produce any warnings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    float x = 300.0 + rand();
    char c = x;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't it produce a narrowing error?

Comment: mh, it should if your `x` value exceed the ascii value of 255

Comment: What does it print? I'm curious

Comment: It prints garbage characters, which is expected, but the compilation prints nothing (no errors or warnings) - We tested on godbolt.org with other compilers and haven't been able to get it to produce any warnings. We have actually tried all kinds of dangerous conversions and haven't been getting any warnings, but I am certain I have seen warnings in the past about converting from int to float (since floats cannot store all 32-bit integers if actually using 32-bit floats)

Comment: I tried to print the `x` value and it's really big (someling like e+9). For sure outside the ascii values.

I'm really noob in c++ so I ask you a question:

Are there some options like `Option Strict ON` in Visual Studio? It must give a warning or something like that.

Comment: There's no casting here. A cast is an *explicit* type conversion. Just sayin'.

Comment: In order to catch narrowing errors, use uniform initialisation: `char c{x};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some research and I found that `-Wall` doesn't warn about type conversion issues.

Instead, use the flag `-Wconversion` in order to get a warning about potential type conversion issues.

***Remarks:***

For the users of VC++, `/W4` will warn you about possible loss of data during type conversions

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri i cannot see anything, just a blank page

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri it does produce a warning on your godbolt link. https://i.imgur.com/WWt4RoY.png