# Why is a double convertible to a const-reference of seemingly any primitive?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, reference-binding

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

float func(char const & val1, unsigned int const & val2)
{
    return val1 + val2;
}

int main() {
    double test1 = 0.2;
    double test2 = 0.3;

    std::cout << func(test1, test2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs despite the fact that I am passing in a `double` to a function that takes a const-reference to types that are smaller than a `double` (on my system, `sizeof(double) == 8`, while `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4`, and `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition). If the reference isn't `const`, compilation fails (e.g.,  `float func(char & val1, unsigned int & val2)` instead of the current definition) with an error:

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'char&' to an rvalue of type 'char'

I get the exact same behavior when testing this with GCC, Clang, ICC, and MSVC on Godbolt, so it appears standard. What is it about const-references that causes this to be accepted, whereas a reference isn't? Also, I used `-Wall -pedantic` - why am I not getting a warning about a narrowing conversion? I do when the function passes by value instead of by reference...

Comment: Narrowing conversions are only ever mentioned in the standard in relation to [list initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7). You aren't doing those so you won't get a narrowing conversion warning. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443036/why-doesnt-c-show-a-narrowing-conversion-error-when-casting-a-float-to-a-char/52443287

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is indeed standard.

`test1` and `test2` are converted to *anonymous temporary* `char` and `unsigned` types for which the `const` references in the function are appropriate bindings. If you set your compiler to warn you of narrowing conversions (e.g. -Wconversion), it would output a message.

These bindings are not possible if the function parameters are non-`const` references, and your compiler is correctly issuing a diagnostic in that case.

One fix is to `delete` a better overload match:

```
float func(double, double) = delete;
```

Comment: Is `-Wall -pedantic` not sufficient? I have that set (as mentioned in the question)

Comment: Nope. There's a separate one for narrowing conversions.

Comment: @R_Kapp [Use `-Wconversion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443036/why-doesnt-c-show-a-narrowing-conversion-error-when-casting-a-float-to-a-char/52443287)

Comment: I really wish gcc had a `-Wabsolutely-everything-and-if-i-complain-im-an-idiot` option. Does `-Wextra` give you `-Wconversion`?

Comment: @Omnifarious: `warning: you are still using c++ [-Wfind-a-pub-instead]`

Comment: @Omnifarious Well, good luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714827/how-to-turn-on-literally-all-of-gccs-warnings

Comment: @Omnifarious: If I ever managed to get onto the gcc development team (Heaven forbid!) that would be my first project.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` usually suffices for me. I don't think that combination has ever _seriously_ let me down.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - The reasoning given misses one important case: I want to know what warnings there are so I can turn off the not-useful ones myself. The manual is not sufficient for a wide variety of reasons. Even if it were complete (which I suspect it frequently isn't) the explanations in the manual only go so far. Really, I want to know what kind of code triggers the warning, then go investigate and figure out if I actually care or not.

Comment: @Omnifarious [you don't want that](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/06/dont-use-weverything/).

Comment: `-Wextra` does not add this either - we need to add `-Wconversion` separately, it seems.

Comment: @Omnifarious • For clang, I use `-Weverything` all the time.  It's great; you want it.  GCC should add that as a switch option.

Comment: @Omnifarious Such a proposition has already been declined for gcc. [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31573)

Comment: @n.m. - I do, in fact, want that, for just the purpose mentioned in the post you link to. In order to discover interesting warning flags that I would like to enable everywhere.

Comment: @Bathsheba anyone can submit a gcc patch. BTW what other warnings for legal, correct code did you have in mind?

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to the accepted answer, particularly the approach

> One fix is to delete a better overload match:
>
> ```
> float func(double, double) = delete;
> ```

one could also approach it from the other way around: namely deleting all overloads that are not exactly matching your intended types of parameters. If you want to avoid **any** implicit conversions (including promotions), you could define `func` as a deleted [**non-overloaded**](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) function template, and define explicit specializations of `func` only for the specific types of arguments you’d like to have overloads for. E.g.:

```
// Do not overload the primary function template 'func'.
// http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm
template< typename T, typename U >
float func(const T& val1, const U& val2) = delete;

template<>
float func(char const& val1, unsigned int const& val2)
{
    return val1 + val2;
}

int main() {
    double test1 = 0.2;
    double test2 = 0.3;
    char test3 = 'a';
    unsigned int test4 = 4U;
    signed int test5 = 5;

    //(void)func(test1, test2); // error: call to deleted function 'func' (... [with T = double, U = double])
    //(void)func(test2, test3); // error: call to deleted function 'func' (... [with T = double, U = char])
    (void)func(test3, test4); // OK
    //(void)func(test3, test5); // error: call to deleted function 'func' (... [with T = char, U = int])
    return 0;
}
```

Emphasizing again to take care if intending to overload the primary function template, as overload resolution for overloaded and explicitly specialized function templates [can be somewhat confusing](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), as specializations do not participate in the first step of overload resolution.